# Get formated order date but hide time in woocommerce

Tags: php, wordpress, email, woocommerce, fetch

I am fetching the order date on my order email template.

below is the code i use to show order date but want to hide time which is shown by default along with the order date.

`<?php echo $order->order_date; ?>`

Please any one suggest in PHP that i can use.

Comment: Have you saved date in TIMESTAMP format I mean date and time are stored together?

Answer (score 0):

There is no inbuilt method in WooCommerce to get Order date (only), so you have to extract the date from datetime using PHP functions like this:

```
echo date('Y-m-d', strtotime($order->order_date));
```

Hope this helps!